# How to bring the colab dark theme to Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, themes, google-colaboratory

I wanna know what theme google colab uses when we switch to the dark mode and how to install that for jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you have to install Jupyter Themes:

```
pip install jupyterthemes
```

Then, i think Colab uses the theme "onedork", so just set it using:

```
jt -t onedork
```

For some more info about Jupyter Themes, you can check https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes

Comment: This completely removes the header.

Comment: @Rabindra if you check the link in the answer, you can see all the possible customisations for the themes.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can just open Jupyter Notebooks in VS Code (the integration is now superb) and have Dark Theme out of the box (by using VS Code themes).

Comment: Audio in jupyter is still broken in VSCode unfortunately, although it looks like they are finally working on fixing it on the VSCode side!

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/151149

Answer (score 0):

Just type

```
jt -t onedork -f roboto -cellw 95%
```

after that, go into the jupyter notebook you just created and go to Settings then Theme and customize it how you see fit:

Settings/Theme/JupyterLab Dark